# boostrap-select error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Boostrap select live search brings an error when typing into the box snapshot [image]

and javascript console error log

```
bootstrap-select.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
    at a.expr.pseudos.icontains (bootstrap-select.js:199)
    at jquery.js:15
    at jquery.js:15
    at jquery.js:15
    at bm (jquery.js:15)
    at bm (jquery.js:15)
    at Z (jquery.js:15)
    at Function.Z.matches (jquery.js:15)
    at Function.filter (jquery.js:15)
    at bj (jquery.js:15)
```

the select option

```
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Mustard</option>
      <option data-tokens="ketchup">Ketchup</option>
      <option data-tokens="relish">Relish</option>
    </select>
```

selecting the options works.

importing the libs from a cdn

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">`

Comment: Did you debug? Evidently you have an `undefined` somewhere.

Comment: haven't defined anything it's a blank bootstrap page with just the select box. @Carcigenicate

Comment: Maybe you loaded `bootstrap-select` before `jQuery`. Try loading `jQuery` first

Answer (score 0):

Hi Drifter I have tried your example with following scripts and css. I didn't get any error. Hope there are some version compatibility issues are there in your code.Please find the scripts and css versions i have used.

```
 <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
```

Please find the plunker link here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1keNc6d4z7Kq7476SRmp?p=preview

Hope it will help you and will work for you too. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add in Application.css

*= require bootstrap-select

Comment: See how do I write a good answer [answer].